# Sql server and browser timezone calculation

Tags: javascript, sql-server, angular, t-sql, momentjs

Following are the timezone values :

```
SELECT * FROM sys.time_zone_info
```

In Javascript, how to populate and match the timezone at DB for calculation? I also have multiple timezones, also need to work in all browsers

Daylight saving also needs to be considered.

I need a dropdown at client side for timezone and that timezone should work with SQL server timezone info, so I can use the following query,

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'20160101 00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'Cen. Australia Standard Time';
```

How can I auto select drop down base on browser timezone ?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're trying to solve? It's not clear from the description unfortunately. Please provide some more details. See [ask] and [mcve] for guidelines on writing a question with high chances of being solved.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you should be storing and working with times in a "foolproof" format such as [unix timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and only use timezone info when displaying data to users - so in the outermost layers of your application.

Comment: I need a dropdown at client side for timezone and that timezone should work with sql server timezone info, so I can use SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'20160101 00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'Cen. Australia Standard Time'; and it is considering daylight saving, my issue is how can I auto select drop down base on browser timezone ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the client's time zone name in javascript, one method is with `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` as detailed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript). See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions) for browser support.

You'll also need a mapping table to associate the [IANA timezone canonical name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to the Windows time zone name in sys.time_zone_info for use in the `AT TIME ZONE` clause of the T-SQL `CONVERT` function. This mapping table can be used for the dropdown as well.